# Django signals not working

Tags: django, signals

I have a custom function that runs when a credit is added to the CreditsHistory table, which is called by a signal:

```
def update_credits(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):
    if instance is None:
        return
    sum = CreditsHistory.objects.filter(member=instance.member).aggregate(Sum('credits_amount'))
    instance.member.n_credits = sum['credits_amount__sum']
    instance.member.save()

post_save.connect(update_credits, sender=CreditsHistory)
post_delete.connect(update_credits, sender=CreditsHistory)
```

Credits are updated everyday for certain members, but the n_credits field in the Members model is not updated for all members who get a new CreditHistory instance. I guess there is some sort of time out happening, or the database can't cope with the aggregation of the large CreditsHistory table for multiple members.. How can I debug this?

EDIT:

```
class CreditsHistory(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    credits_amount = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']
        verbose_name_plural  = "Credit History"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return  u'credits-history/%s' % self.member.user.username

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, member, credits_amount, date, notes):
        creditshistory = cls(member=member, credits_amount=credits_amount, date=date, notes=notes)
        return creditshistory
```

Comment: can you provide code for CreditsHistory model ?

Comment: edited to include CreditsHistory model